# How to determine maximum scale for cytoscape.js png output?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want users to be able to generate high quality images for publication from their cytoscape.js graphs (in fact, this is the major use case of my application).  Since there's no export from cytoscape.js to a vector format, my documentation tells users to just zoom to a high level of resolution before exporting to png, and then my code passes in the current zoom level as the scale parameter to cy.png(), along with full:true.  However, at sufficiently high values for scale, no image gets generated.  This maximum scale value seems to be different for different graphs, so I assume it's based on some maximum physical dimensions.  How can I determine what the maximum scale value should be for any given graph, so my code won't exceed it?

Also, if I have deleted or moved elements such that the graph takes up less physical space than it used to, cy.png() seems to include that blank area in the resulting image even though it no longer contains any elements -- is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `cy.png()` and `cy.jpg()` will export the *current* viewport to an image.  To export the fitted graph, use `cy.png({ full: true })` or `cy.jpg({ full: true })`.

The browser enforces exported overall file size limits.  This depends on the OS and the browser vendor.  Cytoscape.js can not influence nor can it calculate this limit.  For large resolutions/`scale`s, the quality difference between PNG and JPG is negligible.  So, JPG tends to be a better option for large exports.

Aside: While bitmap formats scale with resolution, vector formats like (SVG) scale with the number of graph elements.  For large graphs, it may be impossible to export SVG (even if such a feature were implemented).

Comment: How can I determine the dimensions of the full graph that will be used for png generation (before scaling)?  If I can determine that, I can decide on an arbitrary but conservative maximum file size that will work for the most common browser/OS combinations, and figure out the maximum scale factor for any given graph.

Comment: Never mind -- the limiting factor for downloads seems to be the size of the data url (maximum length = 2097100), which (because it's a compressed format) can't be gotten directly from the image dimensions.  It looks like the best I can do is use the node positions to get approximate image dimensions and a tentative maximum scale, try generating the png, and then if it's too big, iterate decreasing the scale until I get something that works.  That at least is working for me now.